# How to receive GCM message when app is closed or in background?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

When the App is in foreground, the GcmListenerService will be called and I can do performance here. But what if the app is in background? When the app is in background, I can still receive the notification but it is just the notification part without data part. How can I customize the on receive event to receive a GCM message when my app is in background or even closed??

the onMessageReceived() method will not be called if the app is in background. Is there any other method works when app is in background?

Comment: Have you read: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: I have find the solution myself... Still thank you for ansering

Comment: i have same issue . Can you please provide answer

Comment: I think you have to click on the notification to open the app. and the data will be saved in Extras of the intent...

Comment: i am not receiving gcm if app is closed

Comment: @Rahul Chaudhary hey I finally found the solution myself. In the GCM message type there are 2 choices, one is called "notification" and another one is called "data". GCM can only receive the "data" message when it is in the background. Change the type of the message to "data" in the sender side, then you can receive the data on your client. But you will not receive the notification, you should use the received data to rise your own notification by using notification builder locally. Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/63

i have the same problem with him. And in this link there is a solution. When app is in the background, need server side to make a action. The data part will automatically saved in a intent and send to the activity contains that action in the content filter.