# GCM cannot receive message

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

My app use GCM that send notification message, my question is :

My app can receive notification message when app is foreground, but when app is background or killed my app can't receive notification message .

i want to custom a notification view, i do't want that gcm send notification.

Comment: You may want to try the suggested solution in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36779661/how-to-receive-gcm-message-when-app-is-closed-or-in-background) and see if it will help you. As mentioned by OP, when app is in the background, need server side to make a action. The data part will automatically saved in a intent and send to the activity contains that action in the content filter. See this [GitHub post](https://github.com/google/gcm/issues/63) for additional insights.

Answer (score 0):

It is better you shift to Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM). It handles both foreground and background cases of your app.

In contrast to GCM where a broadcast receiver also had to be implemented to receive messages, in FCM we use a service that extends `FirebaseMessagingService`. Your service should override the `onMessageReceived` and `onDeletedMessages` callbacks.

`onMessageReceived` is provided for most message types, with the following exceptions:

- **Notifications delivered when your app is in the background**. In this
  case, the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray. A
  user tap on a notification opens the app launcher by default.
- **Messages with both notification and data payload, both background and
  foreground**. In this case, the notification is delivered to the
  device’s system tray, and the data payload is delivered in the extras
  of the intent of your launcher Activity.

For more information read [FCM Notification for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience)

Comment: thanks, but our project must use GCM , so i want to know how to solve the question  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Service` to handle your code in background even with closed app.

```
public class MyService extends Service {

 static Activity activity;

public void SendNotification(String message) {

   Intent  resultIntent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class); //Display activity when user click notification
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), resultIntent, 0);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_lancher)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setContentIntent(pIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // mId allows you to update the notification later on.
    mNotificationManager.notify((int) System.currentTimeMillis(), mBuilder.build());
}


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Start GCM code here 
    // or
    SendNotification("hi!);        
 }
}
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:exported="false" />
```

to start `Service`

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, MyService.class);
startService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: thanks, but your answer cannot solve my question, maybe you don't understand my question.

Comment: edit your post with the code you were writing for more clarity.

Comment: I use google cloud message to push notification message,  google cloud message cannot receive message when app is killed or in background.

Comment: service mainly developed for background operations even the application was closed. So try to write your GCM code inside service not inside normal activity or fragment.